# rails 4 activerecord column not getting saved

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a accepts nested model and i have set up the form to send the values to the db. But somehow one of the columns called "deactived_by" is being ignored by activerecord while storing the record in the db.

Here is the controller code that allows for the Accepts nested - the column deactivated_by is in there.

```
# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def customer_params
  params.require(:customer).permit(:name, :legal_name, :abbr, :fein, :dnb, :customer_status_id, :customer_level_id, :customer_type_id, 
  :creator_id, :update_by, :last_updated_on,
  :customer_owners_attributes => [:id, :employee_id, :active, :customer_id, :**deactivated_by**, :deactivation_reason]
  )
end
```

After this I am pasting the code from the webrick logs that shows the column value coming in - but being ignored in the subsequent db record insert.

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Sja4vVHQkU4IZLGGdPQ4Nv8hDwUsZtUVj2f8m3XG6cE=", "customer"=>{"customer_status_id"=>"1", "customer_level_id"=>"3", "name"=>"Ms. Lisa Atkins", "customer_owners_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"id"=>"", "employee_id"=>"3", "customer_id"=>"2970", "active"=>"1", "**deactivated_by**"=>"3", "deactivation_reason"=>""}}, "legal_name"=>"", "fein"=>"", "dnb"=>""}, "commit"=>"Submit", "id"=>"2970"}
  Customer Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `customers`.* FROM `customers` WHERE `customers`.`id` = 2970 LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  CustomerOwner Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `customer_owners`.* FROM `customer_owners` WHERE (customer_id = 2970 and id != NULL)
  SQL (11.9ms)  INSERT INTO `customer_owners` (**`active`, `created_at`, `customer_id`, `deactivation_reason`, `employee_id`, `updated_at`**) VALUES (1, '2013-09-02 02:19:54', 2970, '', 3, '2013-09-02 02:19:54')
   (0.6ms)  COMMIT
```

How can this be? - why is activerecord ignoring this particular column?

Any ideas?

Comment: I do have this column in the database. In case anyone is wondering that to be the case.

Comment: thanks for the formatting sevenseacat.